# Given $a>0$ and continuous function $V$ on $(m,n)$ s.t. $\forall\epsilon \in [-a,a]$, $\log(1+ \epsilon V)$ is concave on $(m,n)$. Prove $V$ is affine

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-explanation, convex-analysis

Suppose there exists $a>0$ and a continuous function $V$ on $(m,n)$ such that for all $\epsilon \in [-a,a]$, the function $\log(1+ \epsilon V)$ is concave on $(m,n)$. I want to prove that $V$ is necessarily affine.

The argument in the text :  Since this is true for all $\epsilon \in [-a,a]$, we let $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$ and $0^{-}$, we get $V$ is affine.

Intuitively, it is clear why $V$ should be affine but I'm not convinced by the argument above and why that implies $V$ must be affine. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Write down the concavity condition for the function $g(x) = \log(1+\epsilon V(x))$ and divide it by $\epsilon$.
- Consider the cases $\epsilon > 0$ and $\epsilon < 0$ separately, and note that the sign of the inequality is reversed when dividing by a negative number.
- Now take the limit for $\epsilon \to 0$. Use that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\log(1+\epsilon V(x))}{\epsilon} = V(x)$.

You'll find that $V$ is both concave and convex, and therefore affine.